# Problem in using the freetts for java in linux

Tags: java, freetts

i am not able to run the demo of the freetts library in my system. I have posted this on the forum of freetts but haven't got any reply yet. I am trying to run the HelloWorld demo, When i am running the following command,

```
ant -find demo.xml
```

i am getting the following output:

```
Searching for demo.xml ...
Buildfile: /home/pranay/Downloads/freetts-1.2.2-bin/freetts-1.2/demo.xml
make_lib_dir:
compile_demo_util:

BUILD FAILED
/home/pranay/Downloads/freetts-1.2.2-bin/freetts-1.2/demo.xml:86: srcdir      "/home/pranay/Downloads/freetts-1.2.2-bin/freetts-1.2/demo/util" does not exist!
Total time: 0 seconds
```

I can see a jar file HelloWorld.jar in the freetts/bin folder but when i run :

```
java -jar bin/HelloWorld.jar
```

I get that *unable to access the jar file*, i even tried accessing it becoming a super user.

Please if someone has used the freetts ,help me on this. 
Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. What are the permissions on the jar, i.e. `ls -la bin/HelloWorld.jar`? What are the permissions on the bin directory? What error are you seeing? Do you need to set a classpath (or `-cp`) to include the freetts.jar when you run HelloWorld?

Comment: i changed the permissions to 777 and also had added the freetts.jar file in the classpath earlier

Comment: Also , when i tried using -cp i got the following output:

All general Mode JSAPI Synthesizers and Voices:
System property "mbrola.base" is undefined.  Will not use MBROLA voices.
    FreeTTS en_US general synthesizer (mode=general, locale=en_US):
        kevin
        kevin16

Using voice: kevin16
System property "mbrola.base" is undefined.  Will not use MBROLA voices.
but no sound heard